# Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern

Tags: ios, swift, regex, uitextfield

I am getting the this error message when typing in "asdf" in the `textField` after I `endEditing`:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN (string asdf, pattern ^(?=.*[A-Z].(?=.*[0-9].(?=.*[a-z].{8}$, case 0, canon 0)'

```
static func isPasswordValid(_ password : String) -> Bool {

    /*
    ^                         Start anchor
    (?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])        Ensure string has two uppercase letters.
    (?=.*[!@#$&*])            Ensure string has one special case letter.
    (?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])        Ensure string has two digits.
    (?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]) Ensure string has three lowercase letters.
    .{8}                      Ensure string is of length 8.
    $                         End anchor.
    */

    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*[A-Z].(?=.*[0-9].(?=.*[a-z].{8}$")
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}
```

I call it like this:

```
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

       if textField == passwordTextField {
        if !Utilities.isPasswordValid(textField.text!){
            self.passwordTextField.borderInactiveColor = .red
            print("hi")
        }
       }
       return true
   }
```

How do I get rid of this? Is there some typo or something? I don't get it and I am grateful for every help :)

Comment: The lookaheads are not closed with a parenthesis `(?=.*` The description of the pattern in the commented lines are also different from the used pattern.

Comment: aargh. Rookie mistage. Thanks man :)

Comment: um. Ok one more thing, why is it not allowing "ASDFasdf2134" as valid password? I thought my expression means: At least 1 Uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 digit and minimum length 8?

Comment: Because `ASDFasdf2134` is 12 characters and you are matching 8 chars with `.{8}` See https://regex101.com/r/4vxLK0/1

Comment: oh so I would like to have **at least** 8 characters

Comment: Then use `.{8,}`

Comment: alright, got it. changed that. Thanks!